# Assign value from endpoint to checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to assign values I get from an endpoint to a checkbox

Here is the object

```
{sendOtpEmail: true}
```

I had to do some searching inside the endpoint response to differentiate whether an email value comes back or a cell phone value comes back

Here is my code

TS

```
  otpCellValue: any;
  otpEmailValue: any;

  getOTPChannel() {
    this._loader.start();
    this._subscriptions.push(this._corpService.getOTPChannel().subscribe((resp) => {
      //get endpoint object
      console.log(resp);
      //get endpoint object parameter name
      let keyNames = Object.keys(resp);
      console.log(keyNames[0]);
      //check for email keyword
      if(keyNames[0].includes('Email')) {
        console.log(resp.sendOtpEmail);
        //get value
        if(resp.sendOtpEmail == true) {
          //email value is true so the otpEmailValue checkbox should be checked however it is not
          this.otpEmailValue = 1;
          this.otpCellValue = 0;
        } else {
          this.otpEmailValue = 0;
          this.otpCellValue = 0;
        }
      }
      this._loader.stop();
    }, (error) => {
      this._loader.stop();
      this._errorService.openErrorPopup('Failed to get OPT channel.');
    }));
  }
```

HTML

```
  <input type="radio" name="1" id="1" class="with-gap" [(ngModel)]="otpCellValue" [(value)]="otpCellValue">
  <input type="radio" name="2" id="2" class="with-gap" [(ngModel)]="otpEmailValue" [(value)]="otpEmailValue">
```

I added comments to say what I am doing in the code above

So now I am stuck with why the email checkbox is not checked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not checkboxes but radio buttons. Assuming that you do want the radio buttons (which in your case it looks like it, because it would be one or the other), there are a few things that needs to be done.

Rather than having 2 properties to indicate which option is selected, you could have 1 property for that purpose.

**So**

```
this.otpEmailValue = 1;
this.otpCellValue = 0;
```

**Becomes**

```
this.contact = 'email'; // This line is now equivalent to the ones above
```

In the template, the radio button inputs, need to have the same name for them to behave as 1 input instead of 2, because after all, we only want 1 option selected. The `ngModel` directive now points to the value we want to bind, in our case, `contact`. And lastly, the value should be static. When the **value** of the property bound with `ngModel` matches the value of one of the radio buttons, it will select it.

So, after all those changes we get the following.

```
<input type="radio"
       name="contact-option"
       id="1"
       class="with-gap"
       [(ngModel)]="contact"
       value="cell"> Cell
<input type="radio"
       name="contact-option"
       id="2"
       class="with-gap"
       [(ngModel)]="contact"
       value="email"> Email
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-irqvyv)